# Assign default value to renamed destructured variables

Tags: javascript, object, variables, rename, destructuring

How to assign a default value to a **renamed** destructured variable:

```javascript
class MyClass {

    constructor ( { prop1, prop2, delete: remove, prop4 } ) {

        this.prop1  = prop1
        this.prop2  = prop2
        this.delete = delete
        this.prop4  = prop4

    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference between the default value of a normal destructuring and a destructuring into a different name:

```
constructor ( { prop1 = true, prop2 = false, delete: remove = true, prop4 = 'something' } ) {
```

Or you just go with:

```
  const defaults = { /*...*/ };

  constructor(settings) {
    Object.assign(this, defaults, settings);
  }
```

and avoid all that trouble :)

Comment: This way is much better :)

Comment: I will leave my other answer so other readers can see the difference. Of course, your answer is the accepted.

Comment: @paulo Actually I messed up things here ... This does not really answer 'How to assign a default value to a renamed destructured variable' ... However I have no idea how that could be cleaned up.

Comment: You can edit your answer and add my answer into yours. This way, you properly answer the question and also provide an "edit" with your suggestion for the specific constructor case :)

Comment: Then, I remove my answer.

Comment: @paulo fair enough :)

Comment: Done. Thanks! :)